# If $\gcd(a, ab) = p^3$ then $\gcd(a^2, b^2) =?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

$\gcd(a, ab) = p^3 $, with $p$ prime, so what is $\gcd(a^2,b^2)$?

I was able to conclude that $ab = p^3$, using gcd property.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I suppose you mean $\gcd(a,b)$?

Comment: This problem does not seem to have been posted correctly. Imagine $a=p^3, b=1$, so $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$. Now imagine $a=p^3,b=a$ and suddenly $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=p^6$. Is it possible that the statement of the problem is: "If $\gcd(a,b)=p^3$ then $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=?\;$?

Comment: My list of exercises is with this statement, which I posted. So my list is wrong.

Comment: Could it be that the question is not what "is" $\gcd(a^2,b^2)$ but what $\gcd(a^2,b^2)$ "could be". Because, from what's given to you, and assuming there is no typo in the problem, you can still conclude that $\gcd(a^2,b^2)\in\{1,p^2,p^4,p^6\}$ (I think), even if, without knowledge of $b$, you cannot say what it is *exactly*.

Comment: Yes, it would make more sense. So the question depends on the factors of 'b'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $a\mid ab$, we have $\gcd(a, ab)=a$, i.e. $a=p^3$. Let $k$ be the highest factor of $p$ dividing $b$, i.e. $b=p^kq$ where $p\not\mid q$. Then $b^2=p^{2k}q^2$ and $p\not\mid q^2$ ($2k$ is the highest factor of $p$ dividing $b^2$). Thus: $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=\gcd(p^6,p^{2k}q^2)=p^{\min(2k,6)}\in\{p^0,p^2,p^4,p^6\}$

One can prove that all four results are actually reached for $b=1,p,p^2,p^3$.